# Call AES_ENCRYPT function in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How can I execute this query in hibernate?

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('admin','password')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be of course doable using a Native SQL Query. Or, if you want to use HQL, it should be possible to extend the MySQL dialect and to register the function(s) (not tested):

```
registerFunction("aes_encrypt", new StandardSQLFunction("aes_encrypt", Hibernate.STRING) )
registerFunction("aes_decrypt", new StandardSQLFunction("aes_decrypt", Hibernate.STRING) )
```

Obviously, in both cases, this is not portable.

Depending on your exact needs, there are also [Jasypt UserTypes](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecurityTransparentencryptionofpersisteddatawithJasyptUserTypes) (altough the Jasypt site seems to be down/dead?)